# It is safe to initialize a pointer inside a struct using device_vector::data() method from a locally declared device_vector in the constructor?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have coded some functors that initialize a member pointer in this way:

```
struct A
{
    A() {
        thust::device_vector<int> d_vect(3);
        d_vect[0]=1;
        d_vect[1]=2;
        d_vect[2]=3;

        pointer = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vect.data());
    }

    __host__ __device__ void operator() {
        //code using pointer
    };

    int* pointer;

};
```

The functor coded in this way run without any apparent problem, so I wounder what happens to the data stored in `d_vect`. Reading the documentation I have the impression this data should be destroyed when the `d_vect` goes out of the scope, so I would expect the data point by `pointer`
should get erased, but it is not. Please could some one clarify this thing to me?

Comment: As soon as the vector's destructor is called, the pointer is invalid. In other words, as soon as the constructor is finished. Also, I formatted your code properly.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. The fact it works is an accident and you shouldn't rely on it  *ever* working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct: `thrust::device_vector` is a managed container and frees all allocated storage when it goes out of scope.

Now de-allocation merely updates bookkeeping information about which memory blocks are free to use, it doesn't explicitly overwrite those blocks with say zeros (for performance reasons). You have to do that manually if that's the behavior you wish.